# How to display image in bootstrap div using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to  display an image from database to a bootstrap div, here is my code:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM berita ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $image= $row['gambar'];
    $title = $row['judul'];
    $description = $row['konten'];
    $time = $row['tanggal'];


    echo"<html>";
    echo"<head>";
echo"<title>Business_Blog  | Home </title>";
echo"<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>";
echo"<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />";
echo"<meta name='keywords' content='Business_Blog Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Android Compatible web template, 
Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design' />";
echo "<script type='applijewelleryion/x-javascript'> addEventListener('load', function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>";
echo    "<link href='css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />";
//<!-- Custom Theme files -->
echo    "<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>";
echo    "<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>";
echo "<link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />";  
echo    "<script src='js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>";
echo    "<script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>";
echo"   </head>";


 echo"      <div class='tc-ch'>";
echo"         <div class='tch-img'>";
echo"            <a href='singlepage.html'><img src='images/$image' class='img-responsive' alt=''/></a>";
echo            "</div>";
echo"               <a class='blog blue' href='singlepage.html'> Technology</a>";
echo"               <h3><a href='singlepage.html'>$title</a></h3>";
echo"                  <p>".substr($description,0,200)."<a href=articles.php?id=".$row['id']." > Read more</a></p>";
echo"                     <div class='blog-poast-info'>";
echo"                        <ul>";
echo"                           <li> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'> </i><a class='admin' href='#'>Admin </a><li>";
echo"                        <li> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'> </i>$time</li>";
echo"                        <li> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-comment'> </i><a class='p-blog' href='#'>3 comments</a></li>";
echo"                           <li> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'> </i><a class='admin' href='#'>5 favourites</a></li>";
echo"                           <li> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'> </i>1.128</li>";
echo"                           </ul>";
echo"                           </div> ";
echo"                        </div>";
echo"                        <div class='clearfix'></div>";
                    //<!-- technology-top -->
            //<!-- technology-top -->
echo"                     <div class='soci'>";
echo"                     <ul>";
echo"                     <li><a href='#' class='facebook-1'> </a></li>";
echo"                     <li><a href='#' class='facebook-1 twitter'> </a></li>";
echo"                     <li><a href='#' class='facebook-1chrome'> </a></li>";
echo"                     <li><a href='#'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'> </i></a></li>";
echo"                     <li><a href='#'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-print'> </i></a></li>";
echo"                     <li><a href='#'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'> </i></a></li>";
echo"                     </ul>";
echo"                        </div>";
//echo "<img src=".$row['gambar']." />";
//echo "<p>".substr($row['konten'],0,200)."<a href=articles.php?id=".$row['id']." > Read more</a></p>";
  echo"</html>";  
}

$conn->close();
            ?>
```

Every other code works fine but when I echo `$image` it does not work, but when i use the html code it works `<a href="singlepage.html"><img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>`.the image insert into database successfully,i echo the bootsrap css and other file but it does not work and i dont get error message either.please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like doing a 'view source' to see the html you DID generate, and if it has the proper `images/1.jpg` in it? your browser will not care WHERE that `1.jpg` came from. it has no idea what happened on the server, it only sees what the server sent over. Plus, if that query returns more than one row, you'll be generating broken html with mulple `<html>...</html>` documents.

Answer (score 2):

It is highly not recommended to save photos in database, since datatype will be changed to blob and you will have to adjust type when inserting and when pulling, instead you can save your photos in a folder and save the path in the database as string.
Hope this will be helpful.